# git cherry pick but recive fatal: Unknown commit pick

Tags: git

on my local git have develop branch and feature branch. in  feature branch has three commit with hash code a1,a2,a3. I want to pick a2 to develop branch so i did

```
- git checkout develop
- git cherry pick a2
=> fatal: Unknown commit pick
- I wrong something ?
```

Comment: It's git cherry-pick a2 see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `git cherry-pick a2`.

Note there's a dash between `cherry` and `pick`

Comment: LOL so hard... except I landed here because I had the same question.